# How to make a label with size_hint in kivy python

Tags: python, responsive-design, widget, label, kivy

I'm trying to do a label with size_hint in a floatlayout but I've realized that doesn't work. I want to make a responsive size of label, because the app wil run in different sizes of screen. I'm doing in kivy language, the code is:

```
Label:
            text: "I'm trying to make a label with size_hint_y"
            size_hint_y: 0.6 #doesn't work, always the same size of font
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.36}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'responsive design'? What result do you want to get? The size hint works. You can check it by adding a background to the label

Comment: A responsive screen means that if I change the device i would see the same proportionality in another screen size. For example if I see the app in my smartphone and the label font size is 25, maybe in the pc it's right, but in the smartphone couldn't be seen properly.

Answer (score 3):

```
#doesn't work, always the same size of font
```

size_hint_y controls the size of the widget, not the font. Use `font_size` instead.

Comment: But If I change the screen size using for example another device it's not seen properly because the label is not responsive. I want to get a screen that may be seen in the same way in another devices (smartphone, pc...). With another widgets it can be achieved using the size_hint attribute but I have realized that doesn't work with the label font size.

Comment: The font size is in pixels. To have it related to the widget size, use e.g. `font_size: 0.6*self.height`. To have it be similar on screens with different pixel densities, use `sp`: `font_size: sp(15)`.

Answer (score 3):

I made my font size = the vertical resolution of the screen * the height of the widget * .5. It does not work perfectly, but it seems to work well enough for now.
Since your size_hint = .6, I would try

```
font_size = (Window.size)[1] * .6 * .5
```

I also added did not use a KV file. I do not know if that will make a difference.
My code for a similar program looked something like this

I made variables for the size of the widget and the font size

```
size = (.2, .075)
fontsize = (Window.size)[1] * size * .5
```

Then to add the widget

```
self.button = Button(text = "Press Me", size_hint = size, font_size = fontsize)
```

Hopefully, this helps!